# Why can't I use this as paramter of observe event when I use LiveData with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

I use LiveData in my layout file, and add observe event for some LiveData variable , you can see Code C.

1: Why can I use assign either `this.viewLifecycleOwner` or `this` to `binding.lifecycleOwner` in Code A?

2: I think `mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this) {... }` in Code B can work well, but in fact, it failed, why?

**Code A**

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner  //It can work well
binding.lifecycleOwner = this                     //It can work well
```

**Code B**

```
mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {   //It can work well
mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this) {                  //It cannot work
```

**Code C**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: LayoutHomeBinding 
  
    private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            HomeViewModel(mActivity.application, provideRepository(mContext))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.layout_home, container, false
        )
      
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        //binding.lifecycleOwner = this     //It can work well
        
        binding.aHomeViewModel = mHomeViewModel   
        
        mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        //mHomeViewModel.listVoiceBySort.observe(this) {         //It cannot work            
            myAdapter.submitList(it)
        }
        ...
        return binding.root
    }


    private fun showActionMenu() {
        val view = mActivity.findViewById<View>(R.id.menuMoreAction) ?: return

        PopupMenu(mContext, view).run {

            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_option_action, menu)

            for (item in menu){
                if (item.itemId == R.id.menuMoreActionShowCheckBox){

                    mHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox.observe(this@FragmentHome){
                    //mHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox.observe(this@FragmentHome.viewLifecycleOwner){  //It can work well    
                        if (it){
                            item.title =mContext.getString(R.string.menuMoreActionHideCheckBox)
                        }else{
                            item.title =mContext.getString(R.string.menuMoreActionShowCheckBox)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewLifecycleOwner` is available only after view of the `Fragment` is being inflated. Referencing the `Fragment` `this` for `lifecycleOwner` will use the `Fragment` lifecycle.

You can use `this` (referencing the `Fragment`) before view of the fragment is inflated, in `onAttach()` and `onCreateView()`. While `viewLifecycle` can be used in and after any point after view is completely created, after `onViewCreated()`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Why can I use assign either this.viewLifecycleOwner or this to binding.lifecycleOwner in Code A?

Because they are both LifecycleOwner. Although you generally want to use `viewLifecycleOwner` from `onViewCreated`, otherwise you can get bugs on fragments that are in "limbo state" (`replace().addToBackStack()`'d).

> 2.) `private fun showActionMenu() { ... observe(`

You generally shouldn't "start observing" things that are triggered by side-effects, otherwise you will end up with observers that don't unregister even after your PopupMenu is dismissed, for example.